# How to remove spaces in filenames on s3 bucket programmatically using boto with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, file-rename

so I have 1000s of files on my s3 bucket. But, the names of the files contain spaces. I want to replace the space with '_' programmatically using boto python. How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Snapshot of filenames:
[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didnt execute anything, I tried to lookup on different approaches of getting this task done. No idea so far. One post says copy to another object with a different filename. Not sure if that's efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to rename objects in Amazon S3.

Instead, you would need to call `CopyObject()` to copy the object, and then `DeleteObject()` to delete the original object.

Alternatively, here's a **cheating method** that I use:

- I create an Excel spreadsheet with the name of the files
- Then, in Column B, I create a formula to convert the spaces into underlines, so it contains the *desired* name
- In Column C, I write a command that renames the object, like this:

```
="aws s3 mv 's3://bucketname/"&A1&"' s3://bucketname/"&B1
```

- Test the command by pasting it into a terminal window
- If it works, use **Copy Down** to create the formula for *all* of the files
- Copy that column, paste it into a `.sh` file, then run the file (preferably on an Amazon EC2 instance to reduce network latency)

The AWS CLI `aws s3 mv` command will call `CopyObject()` and `DeleteObject()`.